# Is a Business Manager system user allowed to request access to a page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Our Facebook app is linked to a Business Manager account. We have created a system user for managing all our campaigns. We are in the process of automating permission requests for those pages we don't own, so that we can create ads on their behalf.  ([This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/bestpractice#bm-best-pmd-owns-ads) would be the use case, if I'm not mistaken.)

For this we're using the `<business id>/pages` edge, POSTing a request with the target page ID, access type and permitted roles. Playing around with Graph Explorer, we seem to be able to do this when using a user access token, but not when using the system user's one.

Is this on purpose or are we just missing something?

**EDIT**

For clarification, this is the success response we get when using a regular user token:

```
{"access_status": "PENDING"}
```

Whereas this is the error we receive when using the system user's token:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "You do not have permission to request access to the given object.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3988,
    "error_subcode": 1690095,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Invalid Permissions For Page Access Request",
    "error_user_msg": "Your business isn't allowed to request access to this Page. Please ask the Page owner to grant you access or contact our support team."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. There are two types of system users: `system users` and `admin system users`. An `admin system user` is required for this operation, using a `system user` will fail with the error described above.